# If image is not blank, syntax

Tags: wordpress

I'm hoping someone can help me out with the syntax because everything I tired doesn't work. I want to edit the code below to only output the img if $img if there is something for $img. I think I put the in the $related .= declaration but I can't get it to work.

```
      $img = genesis_get_image() ? genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'related-posts' ) ) : '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . 'alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';
    $trimtitle = get_the_title();
$shorttitle = wp_trim_words( $trimtitle, $num_words = 8, $more = '… ' );
    $related .= '<li><div class="related_content"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $img . ' ' . $shorttitle . '</a></div></li>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is surely wrong:

```
<img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . 'alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />
```

First, you add only a directory for `src` the `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')`

After this, you do not close the `src` tag with `"`

So it should something like this:

```
    <img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . 'nameofimage.jpg" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />
```

You may also need to add html entities for `get_the_title()`

First try only with this:

```
 <img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . 'nameofimage.jpg" />
```

If picture appears, only after then try to add alt to avoid mistakes.

UPDATE

Based on comment of OP, he wants to show image only if there is an image:

From [this site](http://genesis.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/genesis_get_image/) it tells, the `genesis_get_image()` return an image or a boolean `false` if no image.

So you need something like this:

```
$img = genesis_get_image() ? genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'related-posts' ) ) : 'Sorry, no image here';
```

If you want to add a "no image" image, then use this:

```
$img = genesis_get_image() ? genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'related-posts' ) ) : '<img src="/path/to/noimage/image.jpg" alt="No picture" />';
```

Where `/path/to/noimage/image.jpg` is the path to your noimage image.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my syntax mistakes. The image does appear, however I want to add a conditional to see if there is an image. Sometimes I don't have a featured image and it appears as a broken image this way.

Comment: Thank you! this worked out just swell! $img = genesis_get_image() ? genesis_get_image( array( 'size' => 'related-posts' ) ) : '<img src="/path/to/noimage/image.jpg" alt="No picture" />';